# Select command sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following columns in my table:

```
name, company, email, contact, event-day, event-time
```

I want to select all the same times in the time column of a particular day from each row in the table via a SQL command.

My times area a mixture of 1030, 1130, 1230. Days are 17th-july and 18th-july

So for example I'd like to find out how many people have booked the 1030 time slot on the 17th may?

Comment: is this SQL Server, mySQL, etc?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Did you try anything???

Comment: SELECT Name FROM myTable WHERE Event-Day LIKE '17.05%' AND Event-Time = '1030'; something like this?

Comment: mysql. I've only tried this but that just looks for 11.30... $items = SELECT COUNT(`event-time`) AS NumberOfPlaces FROM registered WHERE event-time='1130';

Comment: Please provide the DDL statement for the table. Without knowledge of how your dates are stored, this question is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE event-day='17th-july' AND event-time=1730
```

This will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If your date column is text based:

```
select * 
from tbl
where event-day = '17th-may' and
      event-time = '1030';
```

Otherwise you'll need to use a date literal construction function (such as Oracle's TO_DATE) to build the date you want to compare with.

```
select * 
from tbl
where event-day = TO_DATE('2002/05/17') and
      event-time = '1030';
```

just noticed you were on MySql...

```
select count(*) 
from tbl
where event-day = '2002-05-17' and
      event-time = '1030';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  select COUNT(*) as  NumberOfPlaces 
  from registered 
  where event-day = '17th-july' and
  event-time = '1030';
```